# Set Delays for webpages loading time

Tags: http, html, delay

In the latest xkcd, he stated that a way to combat procastination is to set delays to the loading times of web pages. Which seem like a neat idea.

I do not know wether it is possible to do so on windows, does anyone has an idea wether it is possible and how to do it.

I also have Linux, so both OS work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an HTTP proxy which sleeps for requests to certain domains.

You should probably make it sleep for only the first request every 10 seconds (per domain) to avoid a separate sleep for each image and CSS file.

You might want to change that to 15 minutes (or 5 minutes after the last request) to avoid a separate sleep for each page in the site.